# why tkinter give error with text overwriting?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with tkinter, I'm creating a blasphemy generator (obviously goliardic) with a friend of mine, but I'm having a problem with the output, in fact every time I click on the button to generate the blasphemy the text inserts one under the other, while I would like it to be overwritten, I wanted to know if there was a way to remedy this thing with the attached code inserted.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random

windows = tk.Tk()
windows.title("Generatore di Bestemmie")
windows.geometry('400x500')
windows.configure(bg='gray')

def generazione():
    lista = [" iuvichila vosashirime", " abitante",  " acqua", " aereo", " secco", " aeroporto", " agosto", " aiuto", " albergo", " albero", " inutile", " andata", " animale", " ano", " appartamento", " aprile", " arrivo", " arte", " artista", " attenzione", " auto", " autobus", " autunno", " bacio", " bagno", " bambina", " bambino", " banca", " bar", " barista", " bicchiere", " bicicletta", " biglietto", " binario", " birra", " bistecca", " bocca", " borsa", " bottiglia", " bruschetta", " caffè", " caffelatte", " calendario", " camera", " cameriera", " cameriere", " camicia", " campagna", " cane", " cantante", " canzone", " capello", " capitale", " capodanno", " cappuccino", " carabiniere", " carattere", " carne", " carnevale", " carta di credito"]
    santoinquestione = ["dio", "madonna", "gesù", "cristo"]
    bestemmia = random. choice(lista)
    dioinquestione = random. choice(santoinquestione)

    bestemmiacompleta = dioinquestione + bestemmia

    text_output = tk.Label(windows, text=bestemmiacompleta)
    text_output.grid(padx=2, pady=2)
    text_output.delete(bestemmiacompleta, "insert lineend")

generatore = tk.Button(text="Genera la Bestemmia", command=generazione, bg="white")

generatore.grid(padx=115, pady=210, )


windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hint: where the code says `text_output = tk.Label(windows, text=bestemmiacompleta)`, what does that do? It creates a *new* label, right? What do you expect to happen to the *previous* label created from *last* time the button was clicked? Why?

Comment: @Golden. You having typo error. I should be random.choice

Comment: line 19, in generazione
    text_output.delete(bestemmiacompleta, "insert lineend")
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Label' object has no attribute 'delete'

Answer (score 0):

Using textvariable instead of text param.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

windows = tk.Tk()
windows.title("Generatore di Bestemmie")
windows.geometry('400x500')
windows.configure(bg='gray')

var = tk.StringVar()
text_output = tk.Label(windows, textvariable=var)


def generazione():
    lista = [" iuvichila vosashirime", " abitante", " acqua", " aereo", " secco", " aeroporto", " agosto", " aiuto",
             " albergo", " albero", " inutile", " andata", " animale", " ano", " appartamento", " aprile", " arrivo",
             " arte", " artista", " attenzione", " auto", " autobus", " autunno", " bacio", " bagno", " bambina",
             " bambino", " banca", " bar", " barista", " bicchiere", " bicicletta", " biglietto", " binario", " birra",
             " bistecca", " bocca", " borsa", " bottiglia", " bruschetta", " caffè", " caffelatte", " calendario",
             " camera", " cameriera", " cameriere", " camicia", " campagna", " cane", " cantante", " canzone",
             " capello", " capitale", " capodanno", " cappuccino", " carabiniere", " carattere", " carne", " carnevale",
             " carta di credito"]
    santoinquestione = ["dio", "madonna", "gesù", "cristo"]
    bestemmia = random.choice(lista)
    dioinquestione = random.choice(santoinquestione)

    text_output.grid(padx=2, pady=2)
    var.set(f'{dioinquestione} {bestemmia}')


generatore = tk.Button(text="Genera la Bestemmia", command=generazione, bg="white")
generatore.grid(padx=115, pady=210, )
windows.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- Never put this `tk.Label` inside `generazione()` function. Otherwise,
  it creates new widgets every time you click `generazione()`
- Put this `tk.Label` of outside of `generazione()` function. And leave
  the grid() inside if you want `tk.Label` invisible. Otherwise, put it
  outside.
- Replace `text_output.delete(bestemmiacompleta, "insert lineend")` to
  `text_output.configure(text=bestemmiacompleta)`

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk 
import random

windows = tk.Tk()
windows.title("Generatore di Bestemmie")
windows.geometry('400x500')
windows.configure(bg='gray')

def generazione():
    lista = [" iuvichila vosashirime", " abitante",  " acqua", " aereo", " secco", " aeroporto", " agosto", " aiuto", " albergo", " albero", " inutile", " andata", " animale", " ano", " appartamento", " aprile", " arrivo", " arte", " artista", " attenzione", " auto", " autobus", " autunno", " bacio", " bagno", " bambina", " bambino", " banca", " bar", " barista", " bicchiere", " bicicletta", " biglietto", " binario", " birra", " bistecca", " bocca", " borsa", " bottiglia", " bruschetta", " caffè", " caffelatte", " calendario", " camera", " cameriera", " cameriere", " camicia", " campagna", " cane", " cantante", " canzone", " capello", " capitale", " capodanno", " cappuccino", " carabiniere", " carattere", " carne", " carnevale", " carta di credito"]
    santoinquestione = ["dio", "madonna", "gesù", "cristo"]
    
    bestemmia = random. choice(lista)
    dioinquestione = random. choice(santoinquestione)

    bestemmiacompleta = dioinquestione + bestemmia
     
    text_output.configure(text=bestemmiacompleta)
    text_output.grid(padx=2, pady=2) 

text_output = tk.Label(windows, width=25)
    
generatore = tk.Button(text="Genera la Bestemmia", command=generazione, bg="white")
generatore.grid(padx=115, pady=210, )

windows.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

[image]